# java 7 equivalent of @lru_cache annotation from of python 3.2

Tags: java

How do I implement lru_cache annotation in java 7 using 'concurrent hashmap' / 'guava caching' internally?
Example usage :

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=10000)
public String someIOHeavyMethod(String x){
  String toBeReturned;
  /*
   * IO heavy operations to compute toBeReturned string
   */
  return toBeReturned;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether there is a direct annotation available from Java Collections.

You can use a `LinkedHashMap` and override [removeEldestEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) method as shown below to achieve the `LRU` behabiour

```
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/)